# PNG картинка отображается на сайте как JPEG

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, png, jpeg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PNG картинка отображается на сайте как JPEG

[Вот как она отображается](http://andy.o3d.us/test.html#)

Comment: Странно, у меня `png`

Comment: http://andy.o3d.us/img/logo.png  вот или спамишь ?

Comment: @MrAndy, проблема решена?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Она отображается как PNG, просто Вы скорее всего забыли убрать белый фон.
Уберите белый фон и всё будет нормально.

[Здесь видно, что у неё есть белый фон.](http://andy.o3d.us/img/logo.png) Воспользуйтесь какой-либо программой на подобии *Paint.net* или онлайн-сервисом и удалите белый фон.